# Validating Password and Retype Password

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having two textboxes like this :

```
<p>
<input type="text" name="NPassword" placeholder="New Password"/></p>
<input type="text" name="RNPassword" placeholder="Retype New Password"/>
```

Now,what i want is that on every keypress of Retype New Password It should check if both are same or not.If yes then in green color display it on right side of RNPassword,Otherwise in red color display that both are not same and also disable the submit button of the page.How this can be done please help.

Comment: quick and dirty way. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp Oh and you need to get the value. Search for DOM and javascript.

Comment: @MingtaoZhang Link is different from what i need.

Comment: @MingtaoZhang If you can, [try to refrain from referencing w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: @AlexL I think you gave a wrong link.If it was a joke,it was a bad one

Comment: @user3522121 It's most definitely not a joke. Read the page. W3Schools has some awful practices on it and people new to coding are learning the wrong things from visiting that site. I'm not the first one to link to this, I've seen and read a lot of discussions involving this topic. Let me be more clear as to not start anything... It has good stuff and bad stuff, it's best to stay away from the bad stuff though

Comment: The link is some how works for me. still ... event_onchange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this demo: **==>** http://jsfiddle.net/uP8Q2/

Another demo = http://jsfiddle.net/ALk9Z/

**disable button demo** http://jsfiddle.net/K2Xdc/

2 things to start with:

- use `type=password` ~> http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.password.html
- use `.keyup()` API: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Also next time add your JS code with the post `:)` rest should fit the need.

**code**

**HTML**

```
<p>
    <input type="password" name="NPassword" placeholder="New Password" id="txtNewPassword" />
</p>
<input type="password" name="RNPassword" placeholder="Retype New Password" id="txtConfirmPassword" onChange="isPasswordMatch();" />
<div id="divCheckPassword"></div>
```

**JS**

```
    function isPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword) $("#divCheckPassword").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else $("#divCheckPassword").html("Passwords match.");
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(isPasswordMatch);
});
```

**Disable button demo code**

```
 $('#hulk').prop('disabled' , true);
$('#txtConfirmPassword').on('keyup', function () {
    var password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword) {
        $("#divCheckPassword").html("Passwords do not match!");
    } else {
        $("#divCheckPassword").html("Passwords match.");
        $('#hulk').prop('disabled' , false);
    }
});
```

Comment: exactly what i needed.But i need to disable the button as long as both did not match

Comment: and where is code to disable submit button of form as long as both are not equal

Comment: @user3522121 => **Disable Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/K2Xdc/ `:)` rest should fit the need

Comment: where am i calling this javascript?

Comment: you dont need to call them as they are called in document.ready()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that before submit you can do that in following way

With plain Jquery:

```
<p>
<input type="text" name="NPassword" id="first" placeholder="New Password"/></p>
<input type="text" name="RNPassword" id="second" placeholder="Retype New Password"/>
<span id="error" class="hidden">Not Matched"</span>
```

And then:

**EDIT ONCHANGE**

```
   $('#second').keyup(function(e){
           if($('#first').val() !== $('#second').val()){
                $('#error').removeClass('hidden');
                return false; 
           }else{
             $('#error').addClass('hidden');
           }
    });
```

http://liveweave.com/yVXnIF

If you use KnockoutJs or AngularJs those have ability to bind verification in model itself.

Comment: Is it going to check on each key pressing of second textbox that it is same or not ?I dont think so.I think it will check on click of submit.Am i right?

Comment: So this is not required.I need to check everytime key is pressed for second one

Comment: Please check the liveweave link for practical example